# MFC: Can you change the acceleration of the spin in a CDateTimeCtrl?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, datepicker, mfc

I am using VS-2015 and I'm trying to extend `CDateTimeCtrl` to detect when it surpasses 59' and change the hour accordingly.

The problem is now that when I hold the arrow to increment or decrement, it accelerates and I can no longer check if it changed from 59 to 00 or vice-versa because increasing or decreasing in more than 1' you can go from 50 to 10.

I know about `CEdit` + `CSpinButtonCtrl` but I want to know if it is possible to change the acceleration to one by one minute only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the handle of your `CDateTimeCtrl` object's contained 'spin button' using the class [`GetDateTimePickerInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdatetimectrl-class?view=vs-2019#getdatetimepickerinfo) member function, which will be in the `hwndUD` member of the returned `DATETIMEPICKERINFO` structure.

You can then effectively disable acceleration for that spin control by sending it the [`UDM_SETACCEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/controls/udm-setaccel) message, with `wParam` set to `1` and `lParam` pointing to a 1-element array of  [`UDACCEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-udaccel) structures; set that structure element's time-to-acceleration (`nSec`) to a very large value and (just to be sure) set the accelerated increment value (`nInc`) to 'remain' at 1:

```cpp
    CDateTimeCtrl MyDTC;
    ///...
    DATETIMEPICKERINFO dtInfo{};
    MyDTC.GetDateTimePickerInfo(&dtInfo);
    UDACCEL AccelList[1] = { {UINT_MAX, 1} };
    ::SendMessage(dtInfo.hwndUD, UDM_SETACCEL, 1, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(AccelList));
```

If ~8,166 years (`UINT_MAX` seconds) is too short a time, you could just add more (identical) `UDACCEL` structures to the list.

Note that you cannot simply disable acceleration altogether by passing `0` as the `wParam` argument to the `SetAccel` function (and `NULL` for `lParam`). This is not documented, and, if you try it, the `UDM_SETACCEL` message (and, thus, the MFC wrapper function, `SetAccel`) will return `FALSE`, indicating an error.

Comment: There's no reason to set `nSec` to a large value. Setting it to 0 is sufficient. In fact, the default for spin controls is to have the first `UDACCEL` element set to `{ 0, 1 }`. No acceleration can happen in this case; it always increments by 1. (I changed some speculative wording in the answer to accurately capture the reality, but stopped short of changing this because I suppose it is a bit more opinionated which value would be clearer in the code.)